# Adblock Plus: How do I whitelist a Javascript File to remove antiadblock

Tags: adblock

I am new to stack overflow, this is my first question
I have a specific anti adblock script:
`http://www.pentafaucet.com/libs/advertisement.js`
How do I whitelist this in Adblock Plus, to circumvent it?
P.S. Also, You can use Greasemonkey

Comment: In case it is not clear, you can only whitelist it on your own machine, not others' browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can whitelist this request using the following exception rule:

`@@||www.pentafaucet.com/libs/advertisement.js^`

However, to prevent the site from detecting Adblock Plus I'd suggest using the following filter:

`@@||www.pentaufaucet.com^$generichide` (see https://adblockplus.org/filters#generic-specific)

Note that this filter might not work in other ad blockers since it has only recently been added to Adblock Plus.